# Proof of a greedy algorithm used for a variation of bin-packing problem

Tags: proof-techniques, greedy-algorithms

We are given an array of weights $W$ (all weights are positive integers), and we need to put the
weights inside bins. Each bin can hold a maximum of Max_val, and each weight is at most Max_val. The variation is that the ordering of weights should not be changed, that is, $W_i$ should be inside a bin before $W_j$ is inserted, for all $i < j$.

For this problem statement, intuitively we can see that a greedy approach of filling a bin till its maximum value is reached and creating a new bin for further weights will produce the minimum number of bins. I am unable to come up with a formal proof that the greedy solution is optimal. Any hints or guidelines would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be the solution produced by the greedy algorithm. For each other solution $S$, let $i(S)$ be the index of the first weight at which $S$ diverges from $G$. Let $O$ be an optimal solution maximizing $i(O)$. Thus $G$ places $i(O)$ in bin $j$ (for some $j$), and $O$ places $i(O)$ in bin $j+1$. If we move $i(O)$ to bin $j$ (which is possible since $O$ is ordered), we obtain a solution $O'$ using at most as many bins as $O$, and satisfying $i(O') > i(O)$. This contradicts the choice of $O$.

If we try to run this argument on the unrestricted bin packing algorithm, we will have trouble when moving $i(O)$ to bin $j$, since that bin might be occupied with other elements, not leaving enough room for $i(O)$. In the variant you consider, this cannot happen.

Comment: Why do we need O to be optimal solution maximizing i(O), why not just optimal solution? Thanks!

Comment: This is how my proof works. You’re welcome to come up with another.

Comment: Sorry now I understood, we need that for the final contradiction. But is it ok to assume the existence of an optimal solution that maximizes i(O).

Comment: Since there are only finitely many options for $i(O)$, I don’t see any problems.

Comment: I have recently only started to learn about proofs and proof techniques, So I am unable to grasp why finitely many options for i(O) implies the existence of an optimal solution that maximizes i(O). If there are any pre-requisites that I need to know tell me, it will be really helpful in my learning process. Thanks!

Comment: It’s commonsense. If you think about it for a few hours, I’m sure you’ll eventually get it.

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it. Thanks for the answer:)